# Are funds in 403b accounts and Social Security secure in the event of a depression?

Tags: united-states, retirement, risk, social-security, 403b

Are funds in 403b accounts in the event of a national depression, such as in the 1920s, secure, or are they lost? And since a depression involves the whole nation, Social Security will end, correct?

Answer (score 2):

> And since a Depression involves the whole Nation, Social Security will
>   end, Correct?

Social Security was started when FDR was president in the middle of the great depression. So you can't say it will end just because we have another depression.

> Are funds in 403b accounts in the event of a National Depression, such
>   as in the 1920s, secure or are they lost?

Funds in retirement accounts such as 401(k), 403(b), TSP as well as Roth and Traditional IRA accounts are generally invested it things that can lose value. There is no guarantee that will protect your accounts from dropping in value. Many of these programs will allow you to invest in things that have different levels of risk, so it is possible to find investments that perform in a much more stable way.

The good thing about these types of accounts is that you have control over how your funds are invested. That means you can decide how to act when the market drops, and how to act as the market recovers.

Some people also have pensions, which the employee generally doesn't have control over the investment choices of the funds. In those cases the employer, union, or government makes the investment decision.